# Excel - calculate cumulative figures based on lookup

Tags: excel, sum, range

Simple table within employee names going down in column A and working day numbers across the top from column B - stated as 1,2,3,4 etc up to 31.

Each day we enter hours worked.

At the end of each row I want a sum for the hours worked based on a specified day. Ie if I enter working day = 15 in a cell at top of the sum column it will return totals for days 1-15.

Comment: Have you tried using `SUMIF`?

Comment: Not sure how I’d construct a sum if to do this? I want to be able to just change the mtd reference and it recalculate all rows.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) function and the ampersand `&` to reference the cell containing the specified working day.

If the `1-31` are in columns `B:AF`, and the `15` reference is in `AG1`, try,

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$AF$1,"<="&$AG$1,B2:AF2)
```

in `AG2` and drag down as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use SUM(OFFSET(....)) here.

Assuming your "Working Days" cell is `AH1` and your day numbers are in `B:AF`, an formula for each row (starting in row 2) would be:

`=SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,0,1,$AH$1))`.

This uses OFFSET to return a dynamic range so that you can sum up hours worked from day 1 to whatever day you put in cell AH1.